# Change assembly attribute values after the build in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, attributes

I want to change the assembly attribute like AssemblyTitleAttribute value to something else once the build is done. Is this possible?

Its just that we have two types of builds one is base and the other is obfuscated, so we just want to add some changes to title / attribute values without rebiulding the assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ildasm to convert the assembly to IL, change the attribute value there and use ilasm to recreate the assembly.  This may or may not be considered rebuilding.

However, it's likely just as easy and fast to conditionally compile the contents of the Assembly attributes in your project based on the top of the build.  Developers are likely to be more familiar with this method and it's, IMHO, easier to maintain.