# Using iladsm+ilasm produces a different assembly

Tags: .net-assembly, ildasm

I want to change an attribute in an already-compiled assembly (in the future I might be able to compile my sources twice, but not at-the-moment...). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068189/552510>) suggests that I use `ildasm`, munge the properties in the text file and then re-assemble using `ilasm`. The blog post [Signing a Third Party Library With Ildasm and Ilasm](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vendettamit/signing-a-third-party-library-with-ildasm-and-ilasm/) suggests a similar solution for a similar problem.

**[edit]** I did that, using:

```
ildasm MyBinaryLib.dll /output=MyBinaryLib.asm /all /caverbal
// no munging for now...
ilasm /nologo /dll MyBinaryLib.asm /resource=MyBinaryLib.res /output=MyBinaryLib2.dll
```

and it worked, but it seems that the resulting assembly is missing some stuff - it's 4096 bytes instead of 4608. I compared some text blocks inside the DLLs, and it seems that the following are missing:

- `AssemblyCultureAttribute` - My original assemblyinfo.cs has `[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]`, I guess ildasm ignores that.
- `AssemblyVersionAttribute` - which is weird, since I do see AssemblyVersion using 
  [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).
- `System.Diagnostics, DebuggableAttribute, DebuggingModes` - ILSpy does show a missing `[assembly: Debuggable]` attribute. The .asm file also says:

-

```
  // --- The following custom attribute is added automatically, do not uncomment -------
  //  .custom /*0C00000C:0A00000E*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/*0100000F*/::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/*0100000F*//DebuggingModes/*01000010*/) /* 0A00000E */
  //           = {int32(263)}
  //    //     = ( 01 00 07 01 00 00 00 00 )
```

My question: What are the effect of these things missing?

Comment: This is just blind guessing when you don't show us the command line you used.  My crystal ball puts a buck on you forgetting to use the /resource option to include the .res file.  Required.

Comment: @Hans Passant: You crystall ball, sire, shows much truth, but alas some is still hidden. I now get 4096 byte out of 4608. My commandlines: `ildasm MyBinaryLib.dll /output=MyBinaryLib.asm /all /caverbal`, `ilasm /nologo /dll MyBinaryLib.asm /resource=MyBinaryLib.res /output=MyBinaryLib.dll`

Comment: (original post edited to reflect new findings)